# Clangd goes down when I work with lsp, what could be the reason for the fall?

Tags: language-server-protocol, clangd

Clangd goes down when I work with lsp. However, from clion (it uses a different solution) clangd works stable. What could be the problem? The next stack of Trace falls out, tried reinstalling lsp and clangd, and different versions, the error remains and every 5 minutes of stable operation drops clangd with this log:

```
I[15:01:48.739] Indexed /home/user-name/Sources/Gui/datamodel/QModel.cpp (523 symbols, 50679 refs, 1972 files)
I[15:01:48.778] --> $/progress
I[15:01:48.779] --> $/progress
I[15:01:49.240] Indexed /home/user-name/main/Sources/Engine/ParserTests.cpp (643 symbols, 59880 refs, 2422 files)
I[15:01:49.287] --> $/progress
I[15:01:49.289] --> $/progress
 #0 0x00007f0224d97fda (/usr/lib/libLLVM-13.so+0xb97fda)
 #1 0x00007f0224d9565f llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/usr/lib/libLLVM-13.so+0xb9565f)
 #2 0x00007f0224d957ad (/usr/lib/libLLVM-13.so+0xb957ad)
 #3 0x00007f0223a3e8e0 (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x3e8e0)
 #4 0x00007f022b89ef91 (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xc9ef91)
 #5 0x00007f022b8a0c56 (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xca0c56)
 #6 0x00007f022b868d26 clang::DeclContext::addHiddenDecl(clang::Decl*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xc68d26)
 #7 0x00007f022b87db3d clang::DeclContext::addDecl(clang::Decl*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xc7db3d)
 #8 0x00007f022d2b52df (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0x26b52df)
 #9 0x00007f022be24465 clang::Sema::HandleField(clang::Scope*, clang::RecordDecl*, clang::SourceLocation, clang::Declarator&, clang::Expr*, clang::InClassInitStyle, clang::AccessSpecifier) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0x1224465)
#10 0x00007f022be5ec4c clang::Sema::ActOnCXXMemberDeclarator(clang::Scope*, clang::AccessSpecifier, clang::Declarator&, llvm::MutableArrayRef<clang::TemplateParameterList*>, clang::Expr*, clang::VirtSpecifiers const&, clang::InClassInitStyle) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0x125ec4c)
#11 0x00007f022b62fe13 clang::Parser::ParseCXXClassMemberDeclaration(clang::AccessSpecifier, clang::ParsedAttributes&, clang::Parser::ParsedTemplateInfo const&, clang::ParsingDeclRAIIObject*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa2fe13)
#12 0x00007f022b6320c8 clang::Parser::ParseCXXClassMemberDeclarationWithPragmas(clang::AccessSpecifier&, clang::ParsedAttributesWithRange&, clang::TypeSpecifierType, clang::Decl*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa320c8)
#13 0x00007f022b632706 clang::Parser::ParseCXXMemberSpecification(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation, clang::ParsedAttributesWithRange&, unsigned int, clang::Decl*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa32706)
#14 0x00007f022b634408 clang::Parser::ParseClassSpecifier(clang::tok::TokenKind, clang::SourceLocation, clang::DeclSpec&, clang::Parser::ParsedTemplateInfo const&, clang::AccessSpecifier, bool, clang::Parser::DeclSpecContext, clang::ParsedAttributesWithRange&) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa34408)
#15 0x00007f022b6223e5 clang::Parser::ParseDeclarationSpecifiers(clang::DeclSpec&, clang::Parser::ParsedTemplateInfo const&, clang::AccessSpecifier, clang::Parser::DeclSpecContext, clang::Parser::LateParsedAttrList*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa223e5)
#16 0x00007f022b69f91a clang::Parser::ParseSingleDeclarationAfterTemplate(clang::DeclaratorContext, clang::Parser::ParsedTemplateInfo const&, clang::ParsingDeclRAIIObject&, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::ParsedAttributes&, clang::AccessSpecifier) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa9f91a)
#17 0x00007f022b6a07e0 clang::Parser::ParseTemplateDeclarationOrSpecialization(clang::DeclaratorContext, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::ParsedAttributes&, clang::AccessSpecifier) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xaa07e0)
#18 0x00007f022b6a0d38 clang::Parser::ParseDeclarationStartingWithTemplate(clang::DeclaratorContext, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::ParsedAttributes&, clang::AccessSpecifier) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xaa0d38)
#19 0x00007f022b62bef8 clang::Parser::ParseDeclaration(clang::DeclaratorContext, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::ParsedAttributesWithRange&, clang::SourceLocation*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa2bef8)
#20 0x00007f022b6a2eeb clang::Parser::ParseExternalDeclaration(clang::ParsedAttributesWithRange&, clang::ParsingDeclSpec*) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xaa2eeb)
#21 0x00007f022b60e911 clang::Parser::ParseInnerNamespace(llvm::SmallVector<clang::Parser::InnerNamespaceInfo, 4u> const&, unsigned int, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::ParsedAttributes&, clang::BalancedDelimiterTracker&) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa0e911)
#22 0x00007f022b60e864 clang::Parser::ParseInnerNamespace(llvm::SmallVector<clang::Parser::InnerNamespaceInfo, 4u> const&, unsigned int, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::ParsedAttributes&, clang::BalancedDelimiterTracker&) (/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.13+0xa0e864)
#23 0x00007f022b60e864 clang::Parser::ParseInnerNamespace(llvm::SmallVector<clang::Parser::InnerNamespaceI
Process clangd stderr finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashes in clang's parser code are generally clang bugs (the parser should handle all input gracefully without crashing, even if the code is invalid).

The `libLLVM-13.so` in your stack trace suggests you're using clangd 13, which is several releases out of date. The first thing I would suggest is to try the latest release, [clangd 16](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/releases/tag/16.0.2), and see if the crash persists. (If it does, another thing worth trying is the [latest weekly snapshot](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/releases/tag/untagged-b8d12486ae300b4201e6) of the in-development clangd 17.)

If the crash still occurs in the latest snapshot, please report the bug in the [clangd issue tracker](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/), keeping in mind the tips at https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#dealing-with-crashes.